# Create global method vue on app.js laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want create global method to translate message using [Laravel-JS-Localization](https://github.com/rmariuzzo/Laravel-JS-Localization)

But when i call the method using vue mustache got an error like this:

```
Property or method "trans" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
Make sure that this property is reactive.
```

Here my laravel `app.js` code:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('dashboard', require('./components/Dashboard').default);

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  methods: {
    trans: function (key) {
      return Lang.get(key);
    },
  },
});
```

`Dashboard.vue` code :

```
<template>
 <p>{{ trans('common.welcome') }}</p>
</template>

<script>
 data () {
  return {
   name: '',
  }
 },
</script>
```

`dashboard.blade.php` code :

```
..........

    <div class="col-9" id="vue">
     <dashboard></dashboard>
    </div> <!--c end col-8 -->

..........
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably go with creating a [Plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html). For example

```js
Vue.use({
  install (Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$trans = Lang.get
  }
})
```

Adding this to your `app.js` code *before* creating any components or `new Vue({...})` will mean all your components will have access to the `$trans` method.

---

Alternatively, you can create a [Global Mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin) but these aren't strongly recommended.

> Use global mixins sparsely and carefully, because it affects every single Vue instance created, **including third party components**

```js
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    trans (key) {
      return Lang.get(key)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: @PanjiSetyaNurPrawira I've updated my answer. I suggest using a plugin over a global mixin but I've provided details of both

Comment: Thank u for the explanation i will try it ^^