# Laravel, InertiaJS, make translate from Database function globally

Tags: javascript, laravel, localization, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have made this helper function to translate proper column from database (MySQL).
Database is like this.

```
 Id     name_en     name_fr    name_de
 1      Car         Auto       Auto
 2      Plane       Avion      Ebene
```

My helper function is like this..

```
import { Inertia } from "@inertiajs/inertia";

export default function translate(array, column) {

    let locale = Inertia.page.props.locale;
    let value = array[column + '_' + locale];

    return value ?? 'Missing Translation';

}
```

In my component i call this function like this and it works fine.

```
<script setup>
import translate from "@/Helpers/translateFromDb";

defineProps({
  object: {
    type: Object,
  },
});
</script>

<template>
  <ul class="flex justify-start space-x-6">
    <li v-for="item in object" :key="item.id">
      {{ translate(item, "name") }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Is there a way to import this helper function globally instead to call it on every component?

EDIT: Yeah i know that the same result could be obtained by using a Trait in the ObjectResource, but i'm learning Vue and i was looking to do this with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a plugin and then initiate your app with that plugin.

Helpers/translateFromDb.js:

```
import { Inertia } from "@inertiajs/inertia";

export default{

    install: (app, options) => {

        app.config.globalProperties.translate = (array, column) => {

            let locale = Inertia.page.props.locale;
            let value = array[column + '_' + locale];

            return value ?? 'Missing Translation';

        }

    }

}
```

app.js:

```
import translateFromDb from "./Helpers/translateFromDb";

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    Vue.use(plugin)
    Vue.use(translateFromDb) // inject plugin here
    new Vue({
      render: h => h(App, props),
    }).$mount(el)
  }
})
```

Read this for more information:

https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html#writing-a-plugin

[Create global method vue on app.js laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294594/create-global-method-vue-on-app-js-laravel)

Comment: Really nice. That was exactly what i was looking for.